# Get (String[] args) from Java main in android

Tags: java, android, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I am using a libary in my android app that is designed for standard java. It therefore asks for the "String[] args" that are the arguments in a standard java main function. Is there a way to get those args in android?

I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Comment: This method has no way to tell whether it is being passed the `String[] args` used to start the Java program, or any other `String[]` constructed at runtime. Just pass in the args you need, even `new String[0]` would satisfy the requirement of "a" `String[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get those args in android?

No. You also cannot set those arguments.

However, presumably you call the `main()` method yourself, passing in a `String[]` parameter.

Comment: But the libary class reqire the args from the main method, surely it does not accept any string array? @CommonsWare

Comment: @LukasPetersson: "surely it does not accept any string array? " -- it should.

Comment: @LukasPetersson how would it be able to tell the difference? If it were able to know the command line arguments in order to determine that you aren't passing the "right" ones, you wouldn't need to pass them again.

Comment: the constructor of the libary class checks for null and throws it. How can a random string be accepted but not null? @AndyTurner

Comment: @LukasPetersson so don't pass null. I have no idea what strings are acceptable to this unnamed library, but I can assure you that there is nothing special about the `String[]` parameter of `main`.